# Add extra '\' in absolute file path in Java

Tags: java, filepath

I have a absolute path coming from my JSP page to my servlet. I want to add extra "\" to access the location to my file.

```
String filePath=request.getParameter("file1");
 /*
filePath= D:\work
*/
```

I want in format like "D:\\work" in my **servlet** so that I can access the files reside in work folder.
I tried using file.pathSeperator() and file.seperator() but did not get desired output.

Comment: Unclear. A simple `filePath = "D:\\work\\" + filePath` should work (note, that forward slashes also work on Windows). So you maybe should show what comes in, what you want to get out, and what code exactly you have tried.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose currently in filePath i am getting D:\work which is not the valid "file" format to access location in java as it needs to add extra "\" to make it valid "file" format. I have tried it using it in loop but unable to figure out how to append extra "\" in my path to make it valid.

Comment: Why do you need an extra backslash? On Windows, one is enough after the drive letter.

Comment: Adding a backslash will not make it a valid "file:" format. You need to convert the path to a URI.

Comment: @RealSkeptic In servlet, for accessing file path it is illegal.

Comment: Not sure what a servlet has to do with it. Perhaps you care to show us the part of your code that fails ([edit] the question and add the information, all of it)? Is your web server running on windows at all? Is the work folder on the server on drive D?

Comment: @yagya I would advise you to accept those solutions which helped you in the past. A record of zero acceptance of the solutions turns people off.

Comment: @yagya You don't need to add _another backslash_ in the path. You only need two backslashes if having them in a String literal in Java. To avoid that, I already suggested to use the forward slash because it works in Windows, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filePath = filePath.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

The real question is why you need this at all?

Comment: to access files from folder in servlet.